# When to use a constant in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working through [this](http://chares.ghost.io/lets-make-a-swift-app-part-1/) Swift tutorial and was surprised to see the use of `let cell` in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (see below). The explanation provided by the tutorial author is

```
Use let instead of var whenever you know the value won't change
```

However, won't the value of `cell` change in this code below for each different cell, especially if an old one isn't dequeued, and wouldn't therefore a variable be more appropriate?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as Alarm
    cell.textLabel.text = object.title
    return cell
}
```

Can you please clarify why a constant is appropriate in that code and in what sense the `value` of `cell` isn't changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `cell` is will change, however, you have to look at the scope. That `cell` constant is being defined anew for every iteration of that method. That is, a new constant is created, returned, and the local constant's scope leaves, so when the next call to that method is made, and `cell` is defined again, it's a new constant that we are dealing with.

The rule of thumb is to always use `let` unless you absolutely cannot. This will help prevent you from accidentally modifying vars that you didn't want to modify.

If you were to define cell outside of the method, and then just use:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Then there would definitely be an issue, since you are redefining a constant.

Comment: Thanks, so there's no issue with defining a new constant with the same name?

Comment: Correct, as long as you are within a scope where there will be no clashes on the variable name. Since you are defining the `let` within a local function scope, it will be a new variable every time the method is called.

Comment: Thanks, Why isn't a constant used in the objective-c version of that method?

Comment: Objective-C's semantics don't lend themselves to creating constants in the same way, and instead rely more on creating immutable variables to create a similar effect, for example methods that return `NSString` not an `NSMutableString` to be sure you don't mutate the result accidentally.

Comment: In Objective-C, I commonly do `UITableViewCell *const cell = ...;` to get a similar effect to Swift's `let`. This makes it a syntax error to redefine `cell` to another value in that method.

Comment: @MaxGabriel I don't see why that is necessary. why would cell be redefined to another value in that method?

Comment: It's not necessary, he's using it for the same reason you use let instead of var, to have a compiler check to make sure he didn't make an error.